# C# - How to reduce Form's Opacity onDeactivate event

Tags: c#, event-handling

My Purpose is to reduce Opacity onDeactivate event because the form has the setting "Stay on Top".

I tried to do this :

```
        protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDeactivate(e);
            Opacity = 0.7;
        }
```

All works perfectly (I click on another window and my form's opacity reduces) till I close the form. If I close the form, I get this error :

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Parametro non corretto
> in System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()
> in System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Opacity(Double value)
> in Hazar.Form1.OnDeactivate(EventArgs e) in C:\Users\lrena\source\repos\Hazar\Hazar\Form1.cs:riga 44
> in System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Active(Boolean value)
> in System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmActivate(Message& m)
> in System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
> in Hazar.Form1.WndProc(Message& m) in C:\Users\lrena\source\repos\Hazar\Hazar\Form1.cs:riga 81
> in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are trying to access a property of a control which is in the process of disposing. The `Deactivate` event is raised also after the `FormClosed` event. Meaning, you need to check the `Control.Disposing` property in the `OnDeactivate` delegate before setting or calling any property or method:

```cs
protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDeactivate(e);

    if (!this.Disposing)
        Opacity = 0.7;
}
```

Also you might benefit from the `Control.IsDisposed` property which returns `true` if the control (the Form in your case) has been disposed of. Use it to check the global/class variables if you have any.